# change class name when dragged and dropped and vice versa - jqueryUI - More

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Based on this two examples ( [change class name when dragged and dropped and vice versa - jqueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294510/change-class-name-when-dragged-and-dropped-and-vice-versa-jqueryui) ) and ( [Best way to submit UL via POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287336/best-way-to-submit-ul-via-post) ) I'm trying to build a form, in which I have three lists of categories.

The first one contains the full list, and then you drag the categories you want inside the other to lists, wich are submitted through a form. Let call them Main, First and Second.

What I want to do is to change the class of the ui item but not using a predifined name class as in the below example, but changing the class name automatically by dropping it into the list. So if I drop an item from Main list to First list, I want the script to automatically detect the list name, and change the item class to that name.

I don't know if I'm being clear at this.

Any help would be appriciated.

Here's what I have so far

```
<form action="prueba.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<ul id="todos" class="droptrue ui-sortable" name="all">
  <li class="sortedli">
    1<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='1'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli">
    2<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='2'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli">
    3<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='3'/>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul id="seleccionados" class="droptrue ui-sortable" name="selected">
  <li class="sortedli" style="">
    4<input type='hidden' name='selected' value='4'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli" style="">
    5<input type='hidden' name='selected' value='5'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli" style="">
    6<input type='hidden' name='selected' value='6'/>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" />

</body>



<script type="text/javascript">

var lists = [{
    "listid": "#todos",
    "connectid": "#seleccionados"
}, {
    "listid": "#seleccionados",
    "connectid": "#todos"
}];
$.each(lists, function(i, list) {
    $(list.listid).sortable({
        connectWith: list.connectid,
        opacity: 0.7,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parents('#todos').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).addClass('dropped');
            } else {
                $(ui.item).addClass('sorted');
            }
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parents('#todos').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('droppedli', 'sortedli');

            } else {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('sortedli', 'droppedli');

            }
            $(ui.item).removeClass('sorted');
            $(ui.item).removeClass('dropped');
        }
    });
});

// BOTTOM OF PAGE
</script>
```

I'm still trying to make it work. I guess I have to play with these lines, and change the 'sorteli' and 'droppedli' to get the values of the attribute of the parent list in which I'm dropping the item

```
        stop: function(event, ui) {
           if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('droppedli', 'sortedli');
           } else {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('sortedli', 'droppedli');
           }
           $(ui.item).removeClass('sorted');
           $(ui.item).removeClass('dropped');
        }
   });
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What are the issues? .... We are not going to write the code for you...

Comment: No, please, that was not my intention. Let me edit the question to add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do this, I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Maybe this can help someone in the future.

Regards

```
<body>
<form action="prueba.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<ul id="all-colls-list" class="droptrue ui-sortable" name="todos">
  <li class="sortedli" name="">
    1<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='1'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli" name="">
    2<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='2'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli" name="">
    3<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='3'/>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue ui-sortable" name="seleccionados">
  <li class="sortedli" name="">
    4<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='4'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli" name="">
    5<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='5'/>
  </li>
  <li class="sortedli" name="">
    6<input type='hidden' name='cats' value='6'/>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" />

</body>



<script type="text/javascript">


// BOTTOM OF PAGE
var lists = [{
    "listid": "#all-colls-list",
    "connectid": "#coll-selected-list"
}, {
    "listid": "#coll-selected-list",
    "connectid": "#all-colls-list"
}];
$.each(lists, function(i, list) {
    $(list.listid).sortable({
        connectWith: list.connectid,
        opacity: 0.7,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).addClass('dropped');
            } else {
                $(ui.item).addClass('sorted');
            }
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parents('#all-colls-list').length > 0) {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('droppedli', 'sortedli');
                $(ui.item).attr('name', $(ui.item).closest("ul").attr('name'));
                $(ui.item).children("input").attr('name', $(ui.item).closest("ul").attr('name'));

            } else {
                $(ui.item).switchClass('sortedli', 'droppedli');
                $(ui.item).attr('name', $(ui.item).closest("ul").attr('name'));
                $(ui.item).children("input").attr('name', $(ui.item).closest("ul").attr('name'));

            }
            $(ui.item).removeClass('sorted');
            $(ui.item).removeClass('dropped');
        }
    });
});

</script>

</html>
```